# The maximum number of bits you can shift long word in 68000

Tags: assembly, 68000

It can be something very stupid, but I would like to ask this question to clarify things in my head.

I am doing great 68k assembly tutorial ([link](http://mrjester.hapisan.com/04_MC68/Sect04Part06/Index.html)). Evrything goes well, but I don't understand one thing. Let me quote:

> You can shift using one data register as a shift size, for example:
>
> ```
>       lsl.l     d0,d1
> ```
>
> Now in this example, d1 is shifted left by the number held in d0. 
>   We’ll pretend at d0 contains 0000010F.
>
> For the source operand, only a byte is read as the shift count.  Since
>   d0 contains 0000010F, only the 0F is used.  So, the long-word of d1 is
>   shifted left by 0F bits.
>
> The maximum number of bits you can shift by depends on the size you
>   chose:
>
> ```
> .b for byte gives a maximum shift of $08 bits.
> .w for word gives a maximum shift of $10 bits.
> .l for long-word gives a maximum shift of $1F bits.
> ```

And here it goes: why for byte and 16bit word operation you can use full length (0x08 for byte and 0x10 for 16bit word) and for 32bit long word only 0x1F? Shouldnt it be 0x20 for 32bit long word consequently?

Anyway I don't see a point shifiting byte 8 bits left as this will give always 0x00 as result.

Still I don't understand this exception for long word in this tutorial.

Any help apreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure where they got that from. _MOTOROLA
M68000 FAMILY
Programmer’s Reference Manual_ says that the shift count is the contents of the register modulo 64.

Comment: I see, thanks. I am not sure too.

Comment: For comparison, x86 masks the shift count with `cl & 0x1F` for 8,16, and 32bit operand-sizes, so you can zero a narrow register with a shift, but not a 32bit register.  64bit operand-size masks the count with `0x3F`, i.e. modulo 64.  (x86 shifts have ridiculous CISC semantics for flag setting: if the count is zero, flags are unaffected, so variable-count shift has an input dependency on the flags.  /facepalm).

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks I understand now, so Michael comment is correct.

Comment: @Michael if you make answer with your comment I am going to accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Just a link to the 68000PRM noted in the first comment: http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/motorola/68000/M68000PM_AD_Rev_1_Programmers_Reference_Manual_1992.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use up to 0x1F for the shift size because there are 32 bits in a long word, so there are only 31 bits to which you can shift the lowest order bit before you completely run out of places to shift the bits.

As far as why the processor or at least the assembler won't accept 0x20 as the number of bits to shift, that was a design decision by whoever designed the chip or the assembler. Remember, if the assembler is the gatekeeper unless you manually edit the binary riles. If the assembler does not accept the code, it doesn't really matter if the chip accepts it unless you manually edit the binary.

Comment: Happy to help. Sometimes there are inconsistencies, especially between generations of chips. The 6800 series evolved into the 680x0 series of chips, eventually adding 32-bit instructions.

Comment: 6800 series (two zeros) actually has nothing to do with 68000 series (three zeros), that include 68000, 68010, 68020, 68030, 68040 and 68060 CPUs.

Comment: Also there is absolutely no obstacles to shift 32bit register to *any* amount of bits. If we have `rol`/`ror` commands, every 32 shifts the picture will repeat itself, if we have `lsl`/`lsr`, we'll get all zeros if shifting for more than 31 bits, if we have `asr`, sign extension to all bits will result.

Comment: @lvd so the answer is wrong, then? And the tutorial maker is wrong too?

Comment: Answer could be edited anytime then :) Regarding tutorials, I see almost no point in using tutorials when the original doc from Motorola is still available.